# Unable to connect grpc client to grpc server

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

I am trying to make a grpc client call to server and getting the below exception.

```
RPC failed: Status{code=INTERNAL, description=Thrown from 
handleResolvedAddresses(): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
gracefulShutdownTimeoutMillis: -1 (expected: >= 0), 
cause=java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
gracefulShutdownTimeoutMillis: -1 (expected: >= 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is from a known issue of Netty version 4.1.3 or earlier. See
https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/6954

Your grpc client library should NOT depend on this version of netty. Check your dependency tree whether the netty library does not match the grpc library you are using.

For example:
https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=io/grpc/grpc-netty/1.8.0/grpc-netty-1.8.0.pom
grpc v1.8.0 should depend on netty v4.1.16.Final

https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=io/grpc/grpc-netty/1.7.0/grpc-netty-1.7.0.pom
grpc v1.7.0 should depend on netty v4.1.16.Final

https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=io/grpc/grpc-netty/1.6.1/grpc-netty-1.6.1.pom
grpc v1.6.1 should depend on netty v4.1.14.Final

etc.

Comment: Hmmmm, I'm seeing this even with GRPC 1.9.1. `io.grpc:grpc-netty:jar:1.9.1` seems to depend on `io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.9`, see [dependency tree](https://gist.github.com/galderz/3743e0fcf8dcd984d445c44b590aaf87) output.

Comment: Actually, it's my fault, ignore my last comment.